Ubuntu Server 22.04 Services dead - dmesg.service
I have set up an Ubutnu server 22.04 and noticed that there are services that are not running (they are dead but status enabled).
This also includes
dmesg.service
When I check the status, it looks like this:
sudo systemctl status dmesg.service
○ dmesg.service - Save initial kernel messages after boot
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dmesg.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2024-07-09 16:01:17 CEST; 17h ago
    Process: 1215 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/savelog -m640 -q -p -n -c 5 /var/log/dmesg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2026 ExecStart=/bin/journalctl --boot 0 --dmesg --output short-monotonic --quiet --no-pager --no-hostname (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2027 ExecStartPost=/bin/chgrp adm /var/log/dmesg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2028 ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 0640 /var/log/dmesg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2026 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 79ms

sudo systemctl start dmesg.service
sudo systemctl status dmesg.service
○ dmesg.service - Save initial kernel messages after boot
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dmesg.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2024-07-10 09:54:16 CEST; 1s ago
    Process: 11902 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/savelog -m640 -q -p -n -c 5 /var/log/dmesg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 11929 ExecStart=/bin/journalctl --boot 0 --dmesg --output short-monotonic --quiet --no-pager --no-hostname (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 11930 ExecStartPost=/bin/chgrp adm /var/log/dmesg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 11931 ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 0640 /var/log/dmesg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 11929 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 34ms

Jul 10 09:54:16 v0110 systemd[1]: Started Save initial kernel messages after boot.
Jul 10 09:54:16 v0110 systemd[1]: dmesg.service: Deactivated successfully.

But I can actually look at dmesg:
sudo dmesg
I checked it like this:
$ for i in $(systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled | grep service | sort | cut -d" " -f1) ; do systemctl -q list-units --all $i --state=dead | column -t | cut -d " " -f1 ; done


dmesg.service
e2scrub_reap.service
grub-common.service
grub-initrd-fallback.service
lxd-agent.service
nginx.service
open-iscsi.service
pollinate.service
secureboot-db.service
snapd.autoimport.service
snapd.core-fixup.service
snapd.recovery-chooser-trigger.service
snap.lxd.activate.service
systemd-pstore.service
thermald.service
ua-reboot-cmds.service
ubuntu-advantage.service

My question is: Do the services have to be dead or do I need to take action here?
It is a "normal" ubuntu server on which some services are running. I can deactivate the temperature sensor but what about the snap services?
Is this normal or is there a need for action? Which services should be running but are now dead?

This is perfectly normal. You can also check with the following more simple command:
systemctl --type=service --state=dead

For me this gives 91 services in total, including the ones you list.
For dmesg in particular, this is a "one-shot" service, since its purpose is to record kernel messages after boot. After the system is booted, the dmesg service stays inactive.
You can also run:
systemctl --type=service 

To get a list of active services, but even not all of those are running.
However, what matters is that the service is loaded - in that case, it will start when needed by the system.

Hey, thanks for your feedback!
So I see that correctly:
That the service: dmesg.service is dead but loaded is because the system activates the services when it needs them ?
So there don't seem to be any problems on the system with the outputs?
Thanks for your feedback :-)

I added some more about dmesg in my answer.

Thank you for your great help and feedback!
